# How can I assign a variant of POINTER(c_char) type to a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I call foreign c library in my program using ctypes, I don't know how to assign a POINTER(c_char) variant to a string.

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague, but I guess you should use `c_char_p` instead of `POINTER(c_char)`.